# Функция ajaxComplete() выполняется, когда вызывается или когда завершаются success? Как мне сделать событие — завершение success?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Я хочу написать функцию, которая будет при отправке ajax формы давать ей класс sending, благодаря которому повторная отправка формы будет невозможна. Также будет меняться кнопка отправки (текст "отправить" - на "отправка" и тд). 
Проблема в том, что при отправке в success могут быть другие строки, выполнение которых требует времени. Как мне сделать событие - когда success (в том числе и все вложенные в него ajax) или error  завершатся? Чтобы убрать у формы класс sending.

Comment: "когда success (в том числе и все вложенные в него ajax)" - это что значит ("вложенные ajax")?

Comment: В success может быть еще один $.ajax({ ... }). Нужно, чтобы весь success или error выполнился, в том числе и этот самый внутренний $.ajax (его success или error).

Comment: https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1452&rub=32